# Make operations on several pandas data frames in for loop and return one concatenated data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have many similar data frames which have to be modified and then concatenated in one data frame. I was wondering if there is a way to do everything with a for loop instead of importing and making operations on one data frame at the time?

This is how I was thinking

```py
c = '/disc/data/'
files = [c+'frames_A1.csv',c+'frames_A2.csv',c+'frames_A3.csv',c+'frames_B1.csv',c+'frames_B2.csv',c+'frames_B3.csv',
        c+'frames_A1_2.csv',c+'frames_A2_2.csv',c+'frames_A3_2.csv',c+'frames_B1_2.csv',c+'frames_B2_2.csv',c+'frames_B3_2.csv',
       c+'frames_B_96.csv',c+'frames_C_96.csv',c+'frames_D_96.csv',c+'frames_E_96.csv',c+'frames_F_96.csv',c+'frames_G_96.csv']

data_tot = []
for i in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(i, sep=';', encoding='unicode_escape')
    df1 = df[['a','b','c','d']]
    df2 = df1[df1['a'].str.contains(r'\btake\b')]
    data_tot.append(df2)
```

I believe I should not append to a list but I cannot figure out how to do otherwise.

Comment: don't manually create every filename and path in `files` list. Put all csv files in one directory and use `pathlib.Path` to create `Path` object to that directory and call loop on its `iterdir`. If the directory also has non-cvs files, you just need to create addtional `Path.glob` to capture only `*.csv` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could then do

```py
total_df = pd.concat(data_tot, ignore_index = True).reset_index()
```